# Bitmap image to base64 conversion

Tags: java, android, image-processing, bitmap, base64

I am trying to convert a bitcode image to base64 format. I tried to code like

```
public static String encodeToBase64(Bitmap image, Bitmap.CompressFormat compressFormat, int quality)
{
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOS = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    image.compress(compressFormat, quality, byteArrayOS);
    return Base64.encodeToString(byteArrayOS.toByteArray(), Base64.URL_SAFE);
}
```

generated response is below which does not give me image again.

can someone provide some pointers here? What I might be doing wrong?

> /9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEB
>                                                                     AQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQH/2wBDAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEB
>                                                                     AQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQH/wAARCAMgAlgDASIA
>                                                                     AhEBAxEB/8QAHwAAAQUBAQEBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL/8QAtRAAAgEDAwIEAwUFBAQA
>                                                                     AAF9AQIDAAQRBRIhMUEGE1FhByJxFDKBkaEII0KxwRVS0fAkM2JyggkKFhcYGRolJicoKSo0NTY3
>                                                                     ODk6Q0RFRkdISUpTVFVWV1hZWmNkZWZnaGlqc3R1dnd4eXqDhIWGh4iJipKTlJWWl5iZmqKjpKWm
>                                                                     p6ipqrKztLW2t7i5usLDxMXGx8jJytLT1NXW19jZ2uHi4+Tl5ufo6erx8vP09fb3+Pn6/8QAHwEA
>                                                                     AwEBAQEBAQEBAQAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL/8QAtREAAgECBAQDBAcFBAQAAQJ3AAECAxEEBSEx
>                                                                     BhJBUQdhcRMiMoEIFEKRobHBCSMzUvAVYnLRChYkNOEl8RcYGRomJygpKjU2Nzg5OkNERUZHSElK
>                                                                     U1RVVldYWVpjZGVmZ2hpanN0dXZ3eHl6goOEhYaHiImKkpOUlZaXmJmaoqOkpaanqKmqsrO0tba3
>                                                                     uLm6wsPExcbHyMnK0tPU1dbX2Nna4uPk5ebn6Onq8vP09fb3+Pn6/9oADAMBAAIRAxEAPwD+PXxv
>                                                                     b/u7W6/58cf+zd85H8OMDH615jP99q+hb+2tP7MvfwHfsJBnqeK8Gv8A7ILts2meD269ffj1/Lnr
>                                                                     Xz+D+Bf9w/8A3IfJ/wDyswp7fr/n+979en5gZO3J9Y+E/wBk861+0/7OPrluvv198deK88/0b/OK
>                                                                     uaL9qt83Vsc8Dt3y/v8A7vvnHUAiugzP1P8Ag9418L+Hs/6V2XuP9vHRu+OO/JyDk11nxf8Aj7pm
>                                                                     s27Wmmap068g926/Mcdz+J5BGa/FvxP4w8VW2rXv2XVPsf23rzz/ABdc/n3PJySTXPTeMPFXJudV
>                                                                     9Bj15b3/AMeM9CTXr691/wCAv/5I0+o/3f8Ayb/7c9Y+K2oXXjHXG/0o3lqMegzy455PYe/JPck1
>                                                                     7X8F/hfaYa6+1enPJ7t7/T15I5IXB+R9O8UXXn2o/D/x4D19ev4dRk13+r/FDVLfSDa2v22z6fzc
>                                                                     k/eOf/rj3JX2l8z28v8A4fz/APbsQe1/HD4o6t4qnPwq0O7xpVnnIsOe7Ed+4549RuIwCes+DAs/
>                                                                     A+60trb/AEpdv9pcc8k4789P1wcnGfEvg7BpVsb3XdTuueOST2yegOBjGOTn1JJGfrjwd/wimsi0
>                                                                     vLq7sucYX5ucEjOeozjcPoODt58DF/DJX6ytZN30mtrdVf06vqdOM/26706JNWdleadnr2evRWTd
>                                                                     3Jv7y+H3jC18Q6SxFvwB1x05YHg8ncfx6gjgEdbf+ILPTwQVwFx3J7vjgHI9cdsjJIOa80+H+v8A
>                                                                     ha2gtGtr3H1GRnpzz6g/r1xk+mX3h7SfEW4G6svsgxwew3P3yCQRyMngkDPBJrA8TPVXeiT1eu8+
>                                                                     sWlpfq5a9btHzeL4X05brv7y2d5Wdr7u92r2V46ttN8OP2gD4cJFpafbOcZz1Pz44ycY/XJ/unPP
>                                                                     6/8AFDU/iDBqGbX7H93PX1cDgH0HboccgjJ6Gb4L6XcS2v2RsAcZ29cs/QEE8bRke6n+7WB4vntP
>                                                                     BufD/hj/AEzxBd4yef8AiVcyHPJ746Z4H4bvGzrO9212SSvquaTi7OXbZdPefNfQ8bGY36hzK7au
>                                                                     rbeuztu07JNJbtNpt+cp4X8LeHTe/wBtH7bdDHoO7eufUn8Twc5pdOudVucjSrX+xrQYGbDkdW9e
>                                                                     eCPUnJBIyBWp4G+A3j3xjM13baXe3hPTg8YYg/XPX8VGTxn9B/hP+xN4sAYa50Uj04yTj8CVPvnu
>                                                                     D1/E864oy3Ac39pX7NO196i2TW/Nf4rXbV7qz+GxmMzHH36Wsr9U7yva+97qz1t3vLX4Z0XwrdXG
>                                                                     /wC122MYJwCeucHr7dOvI5Oa9k8L/BfVvEc32W1s+nfI5+ZvUDoF469yTnGf1X8HfsjeDLbKan3x
>                                                                     zwOhc8Lj8OvTPIIJPjXxt+KPgv4W2974d+FmlWXiTxV/z/8AbSsF8/xd8D0IxjJyTXFgOJ8ux6f9
>                                                                     m67Xemzv1lKzbdlrdq6V72v48cErP+0bLSyUvVuy95vXRu72srayPE5tK8AfATQjda7aWWseIL3H
>                                                                     9m6Dk9t3tz347bjnJC5+b/F3jjx58Q9UP9p3f2OzHTTrAN/xKfmbvuySSc+3TnOarW2na74p1069
>                                                                     4lu73Wbo/cxkY5bPOT1PXPI9ycH3fwt4GBa2zZ56cZxjr2x7Z6dxycGnjMaoqSV0+r1SspJdW3vf
>                                                                     S972WjSPGxmdL4bOya9N52Xu31sk303vrEzPh94dG20W6PpzjHGXPrnH491/ujP0x4f8Pldxzhjj
>                                                                     jGe7A/NnqcA/mM5BNL4O8E/KWtrT0H/jz47fiB7kYOK948L+D+ourTcR15292xx37j2wM84z4ywX
>                                                                     168d7a30tvN6pprfv1a1b35jkNO8EJz8uTx/Fx1k/wA+p6Emu407QFt85Xpj+I+p/wAOR7jkg4r2
>                                                                     TRvC8dvn/RTxjs3TLDPP+7+HfJNdYPB9hcZ/0Tp/vf7Q6cnjjOD3PJ5NL/Vj+7L+vket8pf+Bf8A
>                                                                     2584XPg7bu+yDAGTn1ycdCT9AR/9euT1jwwFZjjkY5yf+mnOCP0x6Anqa+0dM8EFdwJxjHG088nG
>                                                                     SOONpPXjp15OVe+CLScFTaew69CzHtnp/Mjrkmni+CrJ8rutb21b1l9l7bK+/ZyaUm0r/wCLZbvV
>                                                                     e/Ztu9/TVLXs7/Ctx4VM4JOMdj+LD1J7/Xkk5ODXFX/hltpzyD+B+Ut/U/8A1sGvvLV/huo3qbXG
>                                                                     duOCeMnnpk9D+L+gryjVfA93g7bXg+3QZk55OSSecnpkHOASfj8bwVmOA5nd6W10d3eVrbJvV295
>                                                                     vTvcNLeWmvld66Ws79PTd3R8F+MPhfpWsF/9EyPlBHI/vY5HI5bOPYg5yCef8EfD8Wur2lta47+v
>                                                                     PJHc+x/M5JJr7oHwn1XW2O21xjA3cdw3OD9ORz+nzUp9O8K/DVX/ALRb7bdfLnT8EZwzAY7ds8HI
>                                                                     3AHJJrtwPE+ZZBzLMmrO1tHZ3cvi1VnKyd73VopLW79jA43M8Am7N6a6tdWtLu6dl2cnpq07v0/w
>                                                                     Z9p8O6Va2drZ4zjPzZ6bsdT/AL3fPTg4Nfo5+yfnybQXQ3HIzyBnk474B24+o25yQcfjRqHxX8Va
>                                                                     hj+zzZaPac/hguOw75HHpnkYyf1K/YN1c3OkM2o6v9svOOMDP3mHc4BA6fVh1Bz+q+Hvi5lvFuZS
>                                                                     y3LV0vZ/zXlZtPdNq2stNNdY39nG8TfE35RT6byT0T/mUbpt2dnum3+gPi7+yrayv7rUrWy+yWWn
>                                                                     Lj1x82f5A/TcAMjn+Cv/AIKCfGfVfjn+0X4jutNu/slp/wAJnx/31IDxk5zgfXjuDn+xj/gpL8cL
>                                                                     T4a/BHW7XTNV+x6r40xpunen/LT1PPQdSev+1z/FL4D8D3XiHxF4j8Z3Nr9stP8AkG+HPt+f7z9/
>                                                                     8cckcjlj+rLeXpD/ANKqH0vDG0vWH/pVQ1NO0PG7n7ZpNkf7voX4+8T1/PoMnOPWPC3hs+Hrc3P2
>                                                                     Y2l3rWO3Xlz3PThf0zySTseHvAzAWlra2/237Fj+0eB2L9+fx9cgZOa7dZ2tg1rodve6xqv+6OmW
>                                                                     9+PuqT65HJ2jPxv1yXn90f8AI90xra30fw8tp9qP+i8HPP8AxNPmkB4z/u8dsn3J9Z8L/A/x9rdv
>                                                                     b6oNKFppQ249vmOTzjrxn8OpGB9z/sa/8E7vFHjGa0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this function :

```
public static String imageToString(Bitmap BitmapData) {

        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        BitmapData.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bos);
        byte[] byte_arr = bos.toByteArray();

        String file = Base64.encodeToString(byte_arr, Base64.DEFAULT);
        //appendLog(file);
        return file;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some misunderstandings here. In your method you are receiving a bitmap (image) by parameter. If you want to pass it to `base64` format, you are doing it right because `base64` format is just a big String, as you can see in your return.

If the error is in your method and in de reverse process (parsing this `String` in `Base64` to `Bitmap`), you can try this function:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream .toByteArray();
```

to encode `base64` from `byte array` use following method:

```
String encoded = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Also, try to use this method to reverse the process of encode:

```
byte[] decodedString = android.util.Base64.decode(yourString, android.util.Base64.DEFAULT);
                            Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
```